# Let's get critical: Feb 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Parenting Stack Exchange](http://parenting.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Visiting a third world country before meeting a newborn](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/16904/visiting-a-third-world-country-before-meeting-a-newborn)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [2,5 year old girl always picks black](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/18031/2-5-year-old-girl-always-picks-black)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How to get a 17 year old son to realize that laundry is not that hard to do and to do it on a regular basis?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/18149/how-to-get-a-17-year-old-son-to-realize-that-laundry-is-not-that-hard-to-do-and)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How can I help my child who is advanced in programming to meet others at the same skill level?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/18167/how-can-i-help-my-child-who-is-advanced-in-programming-to-meet-others-at-the-sam)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Son (22) has to keep initiating contact between son and parents after moving out](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/16882/son-22-has-to-keep-initiating-contact-between-son-and-parents-after-moving-out)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How do I make my son listen to my discipline, not my mother-in-law?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/18192/how-do-i-make-my-son-listen-to-my-discipline-not-my-mother-in-law)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Being a Step-mom to a troubled (or hurt) 5 year old](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/17993/being-a-step-mom-to-a-troubled-or-hurt-5-year-old)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Working mother but unemployed father](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/18108/working-mother-but-unemployed-father)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [What to do about 1 year old boy who keeps pulling hard at his penis and scrotum?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/18005/what-to-do-about-1-year-old-boy-who-keeps-pulling-hard-at-his-penis-and-scrotum)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [20 yo daughter left home to live with a "bad" girl - what should I do?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/17967/20-yo-daughter-left-home-to-live-with-a-bad-girl-what-should-i-do)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---